# Как скачать файл из google drive в консоли

Tags: linux, google-drive

Как скачать файл из google drive в консоли? `wget` не позволяет этого сделать. Раньше можно было сделать так:

Пусть у нас есть ссылка

```
https://docs.google.com/open?id=[ID]
```

Чтобы скачать файл можно использовать wget и ссылку в следующем виде:

```
https://googledrive.com/host/[ID]
```

Пример команды wget:

```
wget -O file https://googledrive.com/host/[ID]
```

Comment: Покажите, как вы пробывали скачать.

Comment: `lftp` на сайт, и через его интерфейс попробовать вначале?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пример ссылки на веб-страницу для первого попавшегося публично-доступного гуглодокумента (идентификатор для краткости заменен на `$id`):

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/$id/edit#gid=0
```

при выборе «скачать как xlsx» google выдаёт такую ссылку:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/$id/export?format=xlsx&id=$id
```

---

т.е., чтобы скачать этот файл, например, с помощью программы *wget*, надо эту ссылку и указать опцию `--content-disposition` для того, чтобы имя для файла было взято из http-заголовка *content-disposition*, а не из *url*:

```
$ id=1bfr4yHoMwjLfnOtQPDUNZsPnhahMKmfx5WqBRiHb01E
$ wget --content-disposition "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/$id/export?format=xlsx&id=$id"
```

пример вывода для использованного id:

```
--2017-08-30 13:19:26--  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bfr4yHoMwjLfnOtQPDUNZsPnhahMKmfx5WqBRiHb01E/export?format=xlsx&id=1bfr4yHoMwjLfnOtQPDUNZsPnhahMKmfx5WqBRiHb01E
Resolving docs.google.com (docs.google.com)... 64.233.165.194, 2a00:1450:4010:c0f::c2
Connecting to docs.google.com (docs.google.com)|64.233.165.194|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet]
Saving to: ‘Пример чек-листа.xlsx’

Пример чек-листа.xlsx        [ <=>                                   ]   6.01K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2017-08-30 13:19:26 (34.6 MB/s) - ‘Пример чек-листа.xlsx’ saved [6155]
```

---

аналогично можно скачивать и в других форматах, указав их в *url* вместо `xlsx` (`ods`, `pdf` и т.д. и т.п.)

---

аналогично можно скачать и «текстовый документ». только в адресе будет не `spreadsheets`, а `document`, и форматы будут немного другие: `docx`, `odt` и т.п.:

```
$ wget --content-disposition "https://docs.google.com/document/d/$id/export?format=docx&id=$id"
```

---

почти аналогично можно скачать и, например, файл, доступный к просмотру по таким ссылкам:

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=$id
https://drive.google.com/file/d/$id/view
```

команда будет примерно такая:

```
$ wget --content-disposition "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=$id"
```

Comment: Не работает с google drive. Он скачивает какой-то гипертекст

Comment: @hedgehogues, вероятно, вы не таблицу пытаетесь скачать. дайте ссылку на что-нибудь публичное, что у вас не скачиваетя, и я постараюсь дополнить ответ

Comment: Разумеется, не таблицу. Файл произвольный

Comment: ну так в произвольном гуглодокументе и ссылка будет несколько иная. во-первых, там вместо `spreadsheets` будет что-то иное, соответствующее вашему файлу. во-вторых, и формат, вероятно, будет не `xlsx/ods/pdf`. // напоминаю, что речь у вас в вопросе (и в моём ответе) не про «гугль-драйв» вообще, т.е. хранилище произвольных файлов, а конкретно про «гугль-документы»: `docs.google.com/что-то-там`. // так ссылку на «нескачивающееся» дадите?

Comment: >> Как скачать файл из google drive в консоли?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7bu3IY41OHWMGxPMVhGeFpnTkk Даю

Comment: @hedgehogues, дополнил ответ